# Docker rebuild of big infra and configuration tool recommandations

Tags: automation

- I've a docker dev infrastructure (~30 containers).
- I've a regular production infra (~ 30 virtual machine) fully configured with ansible.

Now I need to migrate all the docker image to debian, to stick closer to the production. 
To stick to the production I'd like to use this ansible config as well.

But I don't want developers to run ansible each time on their dev. environment to setup their docker.

What are the strategies that you guys would recommend me? Anyone explored this in your companies ?

Answer (score 0):

Host a single dev environment for your devs and give them remote access to it. It is cruel to make your devs do all that on their little machines. This would cause the environment to be individually maintained many times over instead of a single dev instance of the environment maintained by one network admin who has the needed skills to do so. With just one you give them the credentials to use in an apps config and everyone develops using the same resources.

My goal with my developers is they don't even need to know anything about the environment and I just distribute them credentials for an apps config. Then one dev gets one service and everything else is accessed through the network. Now they just have to deal with code and don't even have to know what ansible or docker is nor do they need all the prerequisites running on their machine. They just need git and a code editor.

Bonus points with Kubernetes